# Driving multiple VFD controllers using collected data

Tags: spi, plc, vfd

I have a LoRaWAN sensor network that I setup which collects temperature data from multiple compost stacks and stores it in a database on the local network. I need to convert that data into an output that I can connect to the digital potentiometer input on an Invertek Optidrive E3 VFD, which controls the speed of a blower fan.  In total, there are 8 VFDs I need to connect to, so I need to have 8 separate outputs.

Can I use a Raspberry Pi to drive 8 digital potentiometers, one for each VFD? If so, what additional hardware would I need?

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: thanks, post has been updated

Comment: What digital potentiometer?

Comment: The digital potentiometer on the VFD.  I have edited the question so it is more clear.

Comment: You would normally use VFDs with a digital comms interface like RS485 and these would daisy chain to a RS485 interface connected to a RasPi. As for a ‘digital potentiometer’ which one were you considering? I’d suggest an Arduino like board with 8 pwm outputs. You also need to consider safety and possible failure modes - would uncommanded activation of a fan create a dangerous situation?